# Accessing methods on open form from a parent form c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to access a method in a child form from parent form.I have used the following code to access the controls.

```
Form form = (Form)Application.OpenForms["frmname"];
if (tableform != null)
{
    GroupBox grp = (GroupBox)tableform.Controls["grpbxname"];
    Panel table = (Panel)grp.Controls["panelname"];
}
```

Using the following code I am able to access controls in the child form from the parent form.
Same way I want to access the function/method in the child form.
For ex: from.newmethod();

Is there any possibility to achieve this,without creating new instance of form.It windows application using c#.net

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declaring a method public is not a good practice. you can create delegate or event instead. you can create public delegate for that method and execute that delegate from the outside the class Or you can create Event that you can handle from the outside of the class.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public delegate void dMyFunction(string param);
    public dMyFunction delMyFunction;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        delMyFunction = new dMyFunction(this.MyFunction);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.Show();
    }
    private void MyFunction(string param)
    {
        this.Text = param;
    }
}
```

Now, you can call this delegate from the outside the class

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
        frm.delMyFunction.Invoke("Hello");
        //On Form load this method will be invoked and Form1 title will be changed.
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not getting this frm.delmyfunction.

Comment: I ma not able to access this delegate in the parent form and I have declared the delegate in the child form

Comment: there was a mistake in declaring `delegate`. change `public delegate sub delegateName();` this line to `public delegate void delegateName();`